# Python - Filter function with multiple conditions

Tags: python, filter

I know this is a dummy question, but I didn't find the answer here the way I had in mind

I just want to know if I can apply multiple filters within a single `filter` function

A simple code to try it:

```
def check_odd(x):

    return (x % 2) == 0

l1 = list(range(1,20))
list(filter((check_odd and lambda x:x>=5), l1))
```

Using the code above only one of the filters is applied (the 2nd).

I solved it using:

```
list(filter(check_odd, filter(lambda x:x>=5, l1)))
```

But I wonder if there is a way to group all filters in filter function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just transform the `and` inside the `lamda`, and combine your conditions there:

```python
def check_odd(x):
    return (x % 2) == 0

l1 = list(range(1,20))
l2 = list(filter((lambda x:x>=5 and check_odd(x)), l1))
print(l2)
```

**Update**
You can actually combine any number of conditions from other functions by wrapping them all inside the lambda. Here's an example:

```python
def check_odd(x):
    return (x % 2) == 0

def check_greater_than_five(x):
    return x >= 5

def check_divisible_by_three(x):
    return x % 3 == 0

l1 = list(range(1,20))
l2 = list(filter((lambda x: (check_odd(x) or check_divisible_by_three(x)) and check_greater_than_five(x)), l1))
print(l2)   #prints all numbers that are greater than five, and are divisible by either 2 or 3
```

Comment: Geez, thank you! I tried to write something like this, but I missed not placing  the (x) after the function

Comment: Welcome :) please consider accepting the answer, you get points for that ;)

Comment: Of course! Stackoverflow says that I have to wait 7min, but I'll do that. just another thing. What if I have 2 functions? like f1 = lambda x:x>=5 and try to place f1 and check_odd inside the filter? Doesnt work using l2 = list(filter((f1 and check_odd), l1)) iwth or without (x)

Comment: The answer worked for you not because I added `x` only, it's because I transformed the funciton `check_odd` inside the lambda. You can use the lambda to wrap all your other condition checking functions. I'll update the answer to elaborate further.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that. I was just wondering if I could use 2 independent functions without having to creat another one to wrap both nor modify one of them to include the other

Comment: Well, in that case you should chain the `filter` calls one after the other (exactly like you did), however keep in mind that that is creating a separate list for each `filter` call, and that you can only chain `and` operator using this approach.